# What is the meaning of: "if (!n)" in C language

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int funcion(int n);

int main()
{
    int num = 10;
    funcion(num);
    return 0;
}

void funcion(int n)
{
    if (!n)
        printf("%d ", n);
    else
    {
        funcion(n - 2);
        printf("%d ", n);
    }
}
```

I thought it meant the same as `n != 0`, but this code prints: `0 2 4 6 8 10` .

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @kinrom5 !n means !( n != 0 ) that is the same as n == 0.

Comment: @TomKarzes `!n`, where `n` is an integer, would be the same as `n == 0`

Comment: Also it is generally recommended for programmers to at least briefly study boolean algebra and set theory. De Morgan's laws in particular.

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrect, `!n` (pronounce not `n`) is equivalent to `n == 0` and the code is consistent with this:

- for the first invocation `funcion(10)`, the test is false and the `else` branch calls `funcion(8)`
- for this second invocation `funcion(8)`, the test is false and the `else` branch calls `funcion(6)`
- for this third invocation `funcion(6)`, the test is false and the `else` branch calls `funcion(4)`
- for this fourth invocation `funcion(4)`, the test is false and the `else` branch calls `funcion(2)`
- for this fifth invocation `funcion(2)`, the test is false and the `else` branch calls `funcion(0)`
- for this sixth invocation `funcion(0)`, the test is true and `printf` outputs `0`  and returns
- back to the fifth invocation `funcion(2)`, `printf` outputs `2`  and returns
- back to the fourth invocation `funcion(4)`, `printf` outputs `4`  and returns
- back to the third invocation `funcion(6)`, `printf` outputs `6`  and returns
- back to the second invocation `funcion(8)`, `printf` outputs `8`  and returns
- back to the first invocation `funcion(10)`, `printf` outputs `10`  and returns

The output is `0 2 4 6 8 10`  (no trailing newline)

Note however that your code is inconsistent: `funcion` is declared with a prototype of `int funcion(int n);` and later defined with a different return type:

```
void funcion(int n) { ...
```

This is an error that should prevent compilation.

Here is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void funcion(int n) {
    if (n)
        funcion(n - 2);
    printf("%d ", n);
}

int main(void) {
    funcion(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TomKarzes: of course! Not enough sleep these days :)

Answer (score 0):

You must look at the function: only when `n` is false --- `0`is false in `C`  --- the recursion will end.

While `funcion` is calling itself there is no `printf` executed (the `printf` comes after the recursion), so the order of the values is reversed. Only after reaching `0` the calls to `printf` are executed.

```
    void funcion(int n)
    {
        if (!n)
            printf("%d ", n);
        else
        {
            funcion(n - 2);
            printf("%d ", n);
        }
    }
```

These operator is really difficult to read, may be only for me. I always tend to use `not` instead of `!` because the exclamation point gets lost easily in the middle of an expression. Sure, to use it today we need to include ***iso646.h`***

Answer (score 0):

> I thought it meant the same as `n != 0`

It is the other way around.

`if (!n)` is the opposite of `if (n)`.

`if (n)` is true when `n != 0`.

Therefore `if (!n)` is true when `n == 0`.